# "Math Processing Error" in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, mathjax, android-app

Below are a couple of screenshots take while using the Stack Exchange Android app. As you can see, each has [Math Processing Errors] (although not every MathJax instance brings up this error). When I've opened the same question from PC everything was alright. How can this be fixed?

[image: Math Processing Error 1]

[image: Math Processing Error 2]

Comment: Did you try to refresh the page and see if it persists? (I sometimes get such errors on a PC too and they are typically only temporary.)

Comment: @Quid I've refresed the page several times, but the error persists

Comment: I've asked a question like this on SE Meta and got no answer.

Comment: Can you link to some questions that are getting errors?

Comment: The answers are [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394543/242) and [this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1394415/242)

Answer (score 1):

This appears to have been fixed.  I can't reproduce with the above questions.